# How to sum child values from firebase and store in label. Firebase-Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Here is the screenshot of my firebase]

I am trying to get sum of all the values of Price from firebase. This is example of my code but giving me 0.0 as output.

```
func getSum() {
    var sum: Double = 0
    ref.child("Value").child("-MAHj9q0INTElKixlCCi").child("Price").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children{
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let data = snap.value as? [String: Any]
            let price = data!["Price"] as? Double ?? 0
            sum += price
       }
       print("Final sum: \(sum)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the source data you're working with, and the sum value that you expect from that data.

Comment: This `ref.child("Value").child("-MAHj9q0INTElKixlCCi").child("Price")` gets the child at */root_ref/Value/-MAH...* which has a value of "1" so there's nothing to iterate over. e.g. the for loop is meaningless here. If you replace that loop with *print(snapshot.value)* it will print "1". I don't think that's what you want but that's what the code does currently. If you want ALL of the child nodes of "Value" then this `ref.child("Value").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)` and then the for loop can be used. Also, please don't use screen shots, include your structure as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is loading a single specific child node. If you want to sum all child nodes, you should load all of them:

```
ref.child("Value").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
  ...
```

Since you store the numeric values as strings in the database, you'll need to parse them back into numbers in your code.

```
let price = Double(data!["Price"] as? String ?? "0")
```

The rest of your code seems correct for this case as far as I can see.

---

Since

---

A slightly more idiomatic version of that code would look like:

```
ref.child("Value").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    var sum: Double = 0
    for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let price = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Price").value as! String
        sum += Double(price)
   }
   print("Final sum: \(sum)")
}
```

What's different here:

- Perform a hard cast to `[DataSnapshot]` only once.
- Use `childSnapshot(forPath:)` to look up the `Price` property.
- Hard-cast the value to a `String`, since the property always exists in your data, and is stored as a string.
- Convert the string value from the database to a double in order to be able to sum it.

Comment: I'm getting child uids but not value of Price under childAutoId.

Comment: I added some more things that were going wrong and that could be improved. I highly recommend getting comfortable with the built-in debugger of Xcode as that is the easiest way to spot these types of mistakes.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen, Thank You. Hard Cast DataSnapshot and using path to lookup the property helped solved my problem.